# destinantion-based NAT cisco routers

Tags: cisco, nat

On a Cisco Router I need to translate "NAT" the LAN IP of some PCs based on the destination e.g. Connecting to 172.16.0.0 /24 Transalte to 172.16.0.100 Connecting to 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Translate to a.b.c.d

Any Help Plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `route-map` and `nat overload`.

> **Route maps**
>
> When NAT uses a route map to decide to create a translation entry, it
>   will always create a "fully extended" translation entry. This
>   translation entry will contain both the inside and outside (local and
>   global) address entries and any TCP or UDP port information

For more detaile about fully extended, please see [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk361/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094837.shtml)